# .NET Instantiation Error

Tags: c#, php, .net, visual-studio-2010

First of all, sorry for this extra descriptive question.

I was implementing my own assembly rather calling anything from GAC! I started with a Class Library project in Visual C# 2010 Express edition. The file Class1.cs looked very simple as:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Sample
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public String generateCode(String s, Array a)
        {
            return "function " + s " + "(" + a + ") { return a['#handler']; }";
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Changing either the name of the file to `MyClass.cs` or even the classname to `Class1` does even throw the same exception described hereunder.

The `AssemblyInfo.cs` file contains the following line implemented:

```cs
...
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("en")]
...
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
...
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.3.5.2034")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.3.5.2034")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-IN")]
```

Then using the gacutil tool I registered it in GAC with the following command:

```cs
gacutil /f /i Sample.dll
```

**Note**: In my scenario, the arguments `-f` and `-i` had no effect in registering this file into GAC.

And therefore I came up with the same .dll file that resides in `{ProjectFolder}\bin\Release\` path at `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Sample\v4.0_2.3.5.2034_en_d328b945b0050bbe\` path.

Finally, when I called this using DOTNET class in PHP as

```cs
$sample = new DOTNET("Sample, Version=2.3.5.2034, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=d328b945b0050bbe", "Sample.MyClass");
```

it threw the following error:

```cs
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to instantiate .Net object [CreateInstance] [0x80070002] The system cannot find the file specified.' in C:\Users\*******\Desktop\Sample.php:2

Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\*******\Desktop\Sample.php(2): dotnet->dotnet('Sample, Ver...','Sample.MyClass')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\*******\Desktop\Sample.php on line 2
```

Again If I use the following code, after moving the main class into different namespace as `namespace Sample.DotNet.myCompany;` it threw a different error:

```cs
$sample = new DOTNET("Sample, Version=2.3.5.2034, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=d328b945b0050bbe", "Sample.DotNet.myCompany.MyClass");
```

This threw:

```cs
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to instantiate .Net object [CreateInstance] [0x80131522] ' in C:\Users\*******\Desktop\Sample.php:2
```

**Note**:

- I am using Vista Home Basic (SP 2), Visual C# 2010 Express edition, PHP 5.4.19, Apache 2.2 & 2.4 versions
- I signed this file with no password set at all in Project Properties section.
- I even have included a line com.dotnet_runtime = "v4.0.30319" to my php.ini

This luckily is not seem to be a PHP problem as expected, because I changed the assembly Target Framework from 4.0 to 3.5 Client Profile in the Project Properties section. It then apparently been visible in `%windir%\assembly\` directory, but failed to produce any satisfactory solution.

Moreover, If I even change the namespace from namespace `Sample` to

```cs
namespace Sample.DotNet.myCompany;
```

in the main file for which the class reflects as `Sample.DotNet.myCompany.MyClass`, and apply the same thing, it rather failed to do what I needed.

**Conclusion**: Nothing made any right solution in my case!

**Question**: Is there any way to fix this up? Elaborately, can I use that particular .dll file created using Visual C# 2010 in PHP 5.4.19 at all?

Comment: Do you have any problems with using this GAC-registered library in C# projects?

Comment: I successfully have registered the library unto the GAC. There is no problem just to use gacutil feature. What I faced as glitch was merely been written here. I am unable to call the methods of that assembly I recently been added to GAC.

Comment: You have an error in your generateCode method. You should delete the third quotation in the method

Answer (score 0):

Can you try compiling your dlll to x86 instead of MSIL?

I would go for enabling the fusion log and seeing what is going on there, that way you will able to see from where is trying to load your assembly.

[How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)